# nvarchar column to find the previous date in sql

Tags: sql, getdate

I have followin table schema

```
declare @temp table  
 (
   id int identity(1,1) not null,
   nod nvarchar(50) 
 )
```

in which `nod` column have following data

```
insert into @temp select 'N/A'
 insert into @temp select 'N/A'
 insert into @temp select '5'
 insert into @temp select 'N/A'
 insert into @temp select '7'
 insert into @temp select 'N/A'
 insert into @temp select '31'
 insert into @temp select '15'
```

i want that select stament shoud give me result on following basis

if `nod` value `'N/A'` then it should show `'N/A'`

or if there any numeric value like 5,15,31 then it should show `getdate()-nod date` date column

I have tried following but fail to minus the days and also represent `'N/A'` when `'N/A'` in that nvarchar column

```
 select  DATEADD(dd,case nod when 'N/A' then 0 else nod end,GETDATE()) from @temp
```

[sql fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ca4b/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query would return a `VARCHAR(50)` column that contains either 'N/A' or `now - nod` date as varchar.

```
SELECT
     CASE nod
         WHEN 'N/A' THEN 'N/A'
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 
                      DATEADD(dd, 
                              -1 * CONVERT(INT, nod), 
                              GETDATE()
                             )
                     ) 
     END
FROM @temp
```